# fHow to free the memory occupied by array in Java

Tags: arrays

I am having a array Arr. I want to free the memory occupied by array after its usage.

```
int Arr[] ={1,2,3,4,5};
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
System.out.println(Arr[i]);
}
```

Now after printing all the array values I want to free the memory occupied by the array.
How is this possible in Java.

Comment: Arr[0]=null; will be enough

Comment: you can't assign Object <null> to a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you array Arr out of scope, garbage collector will take care about it and will free the memory according it needs and policy. Nevertheless, if Arr will be in scope for a longer time, you can tell garbage collector that array is not used any more:

```
Arr = null;
```

But such situation is a clear indication that there is something terribly wrong in your code.